# How to plot scatter plot of given two different column values in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have such a data frame

```
import pandas as pd

sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [25,25,25,18,18,18],
                          'AGE': [11,11,12,11,12,13],
                          'RECORD':[1,2,2,1,1,2]})
```

| ID | AGE | RECORD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 11 | 1 |
| 25 | 11 | 2 |
| 25 | 12 | 2 |
| 18 | 11 | 1 |
| 18 | 12 | 1 |
| 18 | 13 | 2 |

I would like to plot number of profiles vs age given this dataframe. My expectation is to have a plot for each age, for example age 11, there should be 3 profiles. Or for age 12, there should be 2 profiles. I tried using df.query, but I ended up confusing. Could you help me?

**Expected output** should look like below. Legend is not necessary for each ID[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `seaborn` but transform your dataframe first:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = (sample_df.value_counts(['ID', 'AGE']).to_frame('PROFILE')
                .reset_index().astype(str))

sns.scatterplot(data=df1, x='AGE', y='PROFILE', hue='ID')
# OR
sns.catplot(data=df1.sort_values('PROFILE', ascending=True), x='AGE', y='PROFILE', hue='ID')

plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have edited my question and showed my expected output. I hope it is clearer now. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Isn't that what you have on the first graph?

Comment: no, because you have plotted age VS record columns. What I want is age vs number of records for each ID

Answer (score 0):

You can specify column name whose values will be used to color the marker points according to a *colormap*:

```
sample_df.groupby(['AGE', 'ID']).count().reset_index()\
    .plot.scatter(x='AGE', y='RECORD', c='ID', colormap='viridis')
```

---

[image]